# What do i put in the getTracker paremeter for Google analytics

Tags: android, analytics

I tried putting in my property id, but that doesn't seem to be the right thing. Here's what I did so far. I planned on creating an instance from my AnalyticsTracker1 class in the onCreate() method of my activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    tracker = new AnalyticsTracker1();
    tracker.getTracker(UA-60706130-1);

}
```

Here is the AnalyticsTracker1 class

```
import android.app.Application;



import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class AnalyticsTracker1 extends Application {

    private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-XXXXXXXX-1";
    HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
        GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.

    }



    synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
                    : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker):null;

            mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What do i put in the getTracker paremeter for Google analytics

You should set the Property_Id inside the class extending the `Application`.

For example for sending a screenview you can call in this manner in your `onCreate()` method
Send a Screen View

To send a screen view, set the screen field values on the tracker, then send the hit:

```
// Get tracker.
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) this.getApplication()).getTracker(
    TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

// Set screen name.
t.setScreenName(screenName);

// Send a screen view.
t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

Ref:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/advanced#sampling

Comment: What exactly is a ScreenView?

Comment: Its an example for sending the current activity to the google analytics

Comment: ok I copy and pasted what you posted onto my main method but  screenName and getActivity() both cannot be found.

Comment: In place of screename, set your screen name here. And you can remove the getactivity() if you are calling in the activity

Comment: Sorry for all the noob questions,hopefully this is the last one. But for screenName, do I put the name of my app ?

Comment: The name of your screen like splash screen, login screen, sign up screen etc

Comment: OK thanks for the replys, but I got a Classcast exception here Tracker t = ((AnalyticsTracker1) getApplication()).getTracker(
                AnalyticsTracker1.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

Comment: Use this Tracker t = ((AnalyticsTracker1) getBaseContext().get Application()).getTracker(
                AnalyticsTracker1.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

Comment: now  get a ClassCastException just like what happened at the very beginning.

Comment: @ThatThatson it works fine for me.. dont know why is it giving you the classcastexception, may be you are making some silly mistake

Comment: for some reason i'm thinking it's this part right here  Tracker t = ((AnalyticsTracker1) .  Since Tracker is mentioned first, but the parenthesis dictates AnalyticTracker1 .